# Color and formatting of Rstudio console output

Tags: rstudio

How can I get console output like this:

[image]

Currently my console looks like this:

[image]

I have tried installing `cli`, `crayon` packages but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? When you use the code in this blog post, what gets returned? https://aghaynes.wordpress.com/2018/07/12/coloured-output-in-the-r-console/

Comment: Thanks. It works now, after I updated R and re-installed crayon.

Answer (score 0):

Using R version 4.2.2 it now works after installing the crayon-package from CRAN.

```
install.packages("crayon")
```

Console is nicely formatted:
[image]